# Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDetailsService'

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-jdbc

I'm trying to create a Spring Boot application which uses Spring Security and OAuth2 to authenticate via a database. I am trying to follow the GitHub examples of this repository ( https://github.com/TechPrimers/spring-security-db-example ) and now facing this error.

The para-phrased StackTrace :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsDervice': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'usersRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'usersRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.Optional com.user.path.to.repository.UsersRepository.findByName(java.lang.String)! No property name found for type AccountUser!

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsDervice': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'usersRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'usersRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.Optional com.user.path.to.repository.UsersRepository.findByName(java.lang.String)! No property name found for type AccountUser!

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'usersRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.Optional com.user.path.to.repository.UsersRepository.findByName(java.lang.String)! No property name found for type AccountUser!

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.Optional com.user.path.to.repository.UsersRepository.findByName(java.lang.String)! No property name found for type AccountUser!

Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property name found for type AccountUser!
```

Here are my classes:

**CustomUserDetailsService**

```
  @Service("userDetailsDervice")
  public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

  @Autowired
  private UsersRepository usersRepository;


  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    Optional<AccountUser> optionalUsers = usersRepository.findByName(username);

    optionalUsers
            .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found"));
    return optionalUsers
            .map(CustomUserDetails::new).get();
  }
}
```

**UsersRepository**

```
@Repository
public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<AccountUser, Integer> {
    Optional<AccountUser> findByName(String username);
}
```

**AccountUser**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class AccountUser {

@Column(name = "title")
private String title;

@Column(name = "firstname")
private String firstname;

@Column(name = "lastname")
private String lastName;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@Column(name = "modified")
private Date modified;

@Column(name = "accessed")
private Date accessed;

/* ... getters and setters ....*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Repository
public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<AccountUser, Integer> {
    Optional<AccountUser> findByName(String username);
}
```

replace with below

```
@Repository
public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<AccountUser, Integer> {
    Optional<AccountUser> findByLastName(String username);
}
```

You do not have Name as part of entity, JPA is not able to find property 
"name"

for ordering you need

> @Repository public interface UsersRepository extends
>   JpaRepository  { Optional
>   findByLastNameOrderByAccessedDesc(String username); }

Here you will find example for jpa query 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html
 specifically under this section **Table 2.3. Supported keywords inside method names**